# Pop Up Message in MS Access 2000

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm trying to have a message box pop-up when I open a particular Access Database and will let me who is checking in for the day and who is checking out for the day. The database is a Hotel reservation database of sorts. Is there code that could look at my text boxes labeled Check In Date and Check Out Date and generate a pop-up of who is checking in and who is checking out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to build a simple (read only?) form based on a query. The query should select only those people who are checking in or out for the current date.

You can automatically open that form every time the database opens. Select Tools | Startup from the menus. Enter the name of your form under "Display Form/Page".

Comment: Thanks thats a great idea I didnt think of.